# CodeIgniter + PHPExcel: What is best way to call this library to CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I have PHPExcel, and I want to add it to CodeIgniter.

Where is the best to copy the files from all CodeIgniter folders, and how do I call it in my controllers/models for regular usage?

**EDIT:**

It's a whole folder that I need to move, and call the main file: `PHPExcel\IOFactory.php`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may add `PHPExcel` to library in Codeigniter, E.g:

```
application > libraries > PHPExcel.php
```

Let say in `PHPExcel.php` library file:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')):
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
endif;

class PHPExcel
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          //
     }

     public function some_function()
     {
         return 'some_function';
     }

}
```

To call `PHPExcel` library, in your Controller. Let say I named it as 
`My_controller.php`:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')):
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
endif;

class My_controller extends CI_Controller
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          //Call PHPExcel class
          $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
     }

     public function index()
     {
          echo $this->PHPExcel->some_function();
     }


}
```

Comment: I see what you did, I have some questions before I try to do this: 

First: to which Directory should I move the PHPExcel folder to? 
Second: How do I apply this after editing my question and since you now know it's a whole folder with files and not only one.

Comment: Well you can create a folder and name it as PHPExcel and move all files into it. You just need to call main file as you metioned - IOFactory.php  For more information...just go to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial: https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/

Got my answer !